# Partial XML Files

Tags: xml, delphi

I am a long time Delphi user, but new to XML. I have a situation that I thought would be common, but it appears not to be. I am connecting to a server that is sending out multiple xml files. When first connecting, the server sends out all complete documents. However, after that, it only sends out information that has change. Is this common practice? (Done in this case to reduce bandwidth on the network). For example, a document may have multiple child nodes, each with multiple attributes. However, the update may be the document with only one child and the one attribute that has changed. I cant find any way to amend an existing document with a partial document.

Example (small one), first time sent:

```xml
<Status TOD="1620548058.4754" Status="Green" Event="R7" PartNumber="1" SubPart="0" />
```

Second time, changes only:

```xml
<Status TOD="1620548061.5434" Status="Red" />
```

Using Delphi 10.

Comment: It's not common practice. You can use a DOM API to alter the original document. Is the `TOD` attribute an identifier?

Comment: If you have the original document loaded in a DOM then you can parse the second document and just update the first. It's probably quite easy to write such code assuming the document structure is as simple as you have shown in the question.

Comment: How does this practice of only sending deltas (what has changed) distinguish between setting an attribute/a whole node to empty and removing it entirely? How is it clear you have to add nodes instead of replacing existing ones? Or vice versa?

Comment: Could we assume that an attribute such as `Event="R7"` is never removed?

Comment: Maybe you could use the function CloneNodeToDoc from Xml.XMLDoc as an inspiration to write you own MergeNodeToDoc

Comment: Thanks everyone, but @Olivier probably answer my question when he said it is not common practice, and no one seems to have a similar situation. I have solutions in mind, just wanted to put it out there incase something already existed. David this is an abbreviation of the simplest document - they do get quite complex. AmigoJack, the indications for this do exist, particularly in the more complex documents. I think they are quite specific to this application, so even if a solution did exist, it would probably need massaging for this application. dwrbubr, I think you're onto something.